# How to use rosbag::Recorder (C++ API)

Tags: c++, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello together,

I'm new to ROS. I want to record two camera topics to a bag-file with help of the c++ API of rosbag. In this namespace I found the class Recorder, which seems to work like the command line tool rosbag. Unfortunately this class has just a public function to run ( run() ) the recorder, but there is now function to stop it. Has somebody an idea how to use it? Or is it better to use the rosbag::write() function?

Thanks in advance
Klaus

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42714/how-to-use-rosbag::recorder-(c++-api)/) by [LetThemDance](https://answers.ros.org/users/3116/letthemdance/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-08-30

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2015-09-23**:
I tried deleting the recorder object when I was done with it, but it dies messily `usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/condition_variable.hpp:168: boost::condition_variable_any::~condition_variable_any(): Assertion !pthread_mutex_destroy(&internal_mutex)' failed. Aborted (core dumped)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure about stopping the recording through the API, but an alternative solution may be to start/stop bagging when your camera nodes start/stop running.  You can do this by including rosbag in your launch file.  .

---

Originally posted by [amittleider](https://answers.ros.org/users/2448/amittleider/) with karma: 227 on 2013-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0